# Inner text using javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a datatable and I want to extract the column 1

```
var usernames = dataTableTeamMembers.columns(1).data();
```

But it gives me an array like this:

```
Array(2)
0
:
"<a href="#">admin</a>"
1
:
"<a href="#">catalao</a>"
```

I only want the text, not the html.

How do I extract the innertext of that a tag?

Comment: What lib are you using for `dataTableTeamMembers` ? This is crucial information to get efficient help

Comment: `var dataTableTeamMembers = $('#dataTableTeamMembers').DataTable()`

Comment: what lib is `DataTable`? is it [this one](https://datatables.net/)?

Comment: Do you want to access to dataset objects or inner html of the table? This may result in 2 different solutions.

Comment: @Adelin yes....

Comment: @bmvr i dont know

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48623735/295783 to see how to make a [mcve] - click the `<>` snippet editor and give us such full examples

Answer (score 2):

There's two approaches:
With [.column()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column()) (with each one):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dataTableTeamMembers = $('#example').DataTable();
    
    dataTableTeamMembers.column(1).data().each(function(username, index){
      console.log(username);
    });
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>


<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Tiger</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Garrett</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Tiger</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Ashton</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Garrett</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And [.columns()](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) (returns array):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dataTableTeamMembers = $('#example').DataTable();
    
    console.log(dataTableTeamMembers.columns(1).data()[0]);
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>


<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Tiger</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Garrett</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Tiger</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Ashton</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Garrett</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Above and beyond example

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options, depending on what you need

**1 using DataTables API**

```
var table = $('#your_table_id').DataTable().data();

for(var i = 0; i < table.length; i++)
{
    var tbl_obj = table[i];

    //do stuff

    console.log(JSON.stringify(table[i]))
}
```

**2 Using jquery to get all row html**

```
$('#your_table_id tr').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).html());    
 });
```

**3 to get a specific cell on a row, by cell class**

```
 $('#your_table_id tr').each(function() {
    var obj = $(this).find(".cell_class").html();    
 });
```

Use the one which fits more to your needs.